# Redirect folder to site home page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to use .htaccess to redirect people snooping into my indexs/folders to a page

Ex; if someone found site.com/pics/1.jpg and tried to see site.com/pics they would be redirected to a url of my choosing or homepage

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify: going to the exact file, such as `site.com/pics/1.jpg` is allowed, but browsing the folder by going to `site.com/pics` is blocked. Is that the goal?

Comment: If you are using a web server like Nginx or Apache they have their own way of handling routing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow browsing to a specific file such as `site.com/pics/1.jpg` but prevent the directory url (`site.com/pics/`) from showing all files in that folder, place a `.htaccess` file in the pics folder and fill it with:

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pics/?$   /newpage.html
```

The `-Indexes` will forbid folder surfing, and the `RewriteRule` will redirect to `site.com/newpage.html`

Comment: I have that now but I want whoever goes to /pics to be redirected to another page

Comment: That's not enough info for me to figure out what's wrong. Maybe the path you used `/newpage.html` in my example is incorrect.  Maybe your server doesn't have `mod_rewrite` so that these rules caused an error. To investigate, I would first look at the network tab in the browser's dev tools while I navigate to the protected folder. You should see a response code such as `200` or `500` next to the network request. What is it?